# CSS selector to allow one thing but not another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In short, I am trying to grab a sub collection of items based off of id. I am trying to grab `1-1, 1-1-0, 1-1-1` but not `1-19, 1-19-0, 1-19-1`. Is there any way to achieve this?

```js
$(function(){
    
  // grabs all items but only want 1-1 items.
  $('[data-parent-id^=1-1]').prop('checked',true);  
  
  // does not grab the first item 1-1.
  $('[data-parent-id^=1-2-]').prop('checked',true);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" data-parent-id="1-1">
<input type="checkbox" data-parent-id="1-1-0">
<input type="checkbox" data-parent-id="1-1-1">    
<input type="checkbox" data-parent-id="1-19">
<input type="checkbox" data-parent-id="1-19-0">
<input type="checkbox" data-parent-id="1-19-1">
  </div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" data-parent-id="1-2">
<input type="checkbox" data-parent-id="1-2-0">
<input type="checkbox" data-parent-id="1-2-1">    
<input type="checkbox" data-parent-id="1-29">
<input type="checkbox" data-parent-id="1-29-0">
<input type="checkbox" data-parent-id="1-29-1">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this will do the trick:

```
$('[data-parent-id="1-1"], [data-parent-id^="1-1-"]').prop('checked',true);
```

Explanation: the first part of the selector gets exactly `1-1`, the second part gets anything that begins with `1-1-`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution by Mooseman is the simplest one.  You can also use regex and filter the elements with more precision: http://jsfiddle.net/6hfryod2/.

```
$(function(){
    $("div > input[type='checkbox']").filter(function(index) {
        return /^(1-1)$|^(1-1-)/gi.test($(this).attr("data-parent-id"));
    }).prop("checked", true);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way of doing it, using the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$('[data-parent-id^=1-1]:not([data-parent-id^=1-19])').prop('checked',true);
```

where:

- `[data-parent-id^=1-1]` matches all attributes starting with `1-1`:

  - `1-1`
  - `1-1-0`
  - `1-1-1`
  - `1-19`
  - `1-19-0`
  - `1-19-1`
- `:not([data-parent-id^=1-19])` excludes all attributes starting with `1-19`:

  - `1-19`
  - `1-19-0`
  - `1-19-1`